# why without calling the notify wait is releasing the lock

Tags: java, multithreading

Please see the below code, where the notifyAll is commented. Still the main thread is printing the total? How is it possible?

```
public class ThreadA {
public static void main(String[] args){
    ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
    b.start();

    synchronized(b){
        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
            b.wait();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
    }
}}

class ThreadB extends Thread{
int total;
@Override
public void run(){
    synchronized(this){
        for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
            total += i;
        }
       // notify();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try synchronizing on an simple object and not the Thread object and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see is the result of something documented in the javadoc of [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29):

> As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked.

Note that it goes on with

> It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances

Also note that a thread blocked on wait() can go out of its waiting state without any notification, due to spurious wakeups. And the javadoc of wait() clearly explains that wait() should always be called inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Also note:  The Java API doc for Object.wait() says, "...interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop."

That is generally true in other APIs and other languages as well.  A method/function should never assume that the condition it was waiting for is true just because a wait() operation on a condition variable returned.  There should always be a loop.  In pseudo-code:

```
lock mutex
while (! ok_to_do_whatever()) {
    wait on condition_variable
}
do_whatever()
unlock mutex
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this and the waiting thread will wait forever...

```
public class ThreadA {

    public static Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized(lock){
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                lock.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
            }
        }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread
{
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(ThreadA.lock){
            for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
                total += i;
            }
            // notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Of course it does. OP was wondering why main thread could be woken up without ThreadB calling notify. Reason being he had a lock on a Thread object and as a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked.